# Does Stack Exchange have a policy about supporting sites' occasional competitions by providing swag for prizes or otherwise?

Tags: discussion, policy, swag, contest

Firstly, since this was not apparent, I'm a [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com) contributor since it was in Area 51. I don't have a company or an organization or even a job right now. I'm an independent traveller hitchhiking around East Asia.

Now over on the Travel site I just came up with what I think is a great little idea for a site competition in the Travel community.

But before I post the idea on our meta over there I wondered if Stack Exchange already has some policy or whatever of supporting per-site contests made and run by the site's contributors.

It surely must have come up before but I haven't succeeded in finding anything yet on Meta.

A few of us including at least one mod are discussing it in [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) at the moment but I thought I'd dig into the archives here to find out what other SE sites have done before.

Comment: Have you read all the discussions on the [tag:self-promotion] tag?  Maybe it should be applied to this question also.

Comment: @BenVoigt self promotion? It's not like he has a company he's trying to promote or anything.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Did you mean "site promotion"? Otherwise I can't fathom any connection \-:

Comment: @BenVoigt: Really? I don't have an organization. Unless by “your organization" you mean "travel.stackexchange.com" which I think of as my community but Stack Exchange's organization or property or well I'm not sure exactly. Let me go over the wording to see what is not as clear as I thought ... OK I updated the wording of the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: heh, no, we run comps on travel.SE quite often, but they're internal, like 'most bounties in a month'.  @hippietrail is saying he'd like to do another one (coolest travel photo, with some criteria) and suddenly wondered if SE would throw in some swag. There's no commercial interest at all.

Comment: Wow! I'm getting downvoted for asking about this?? \-:

Comment: @hippietrail This is Meta. They downvote you if they want to answer "no" but don't want to explain why. Also, they'll downvote you for lack of freehand circles.

Comment: In this case the only "they" who can answer would be representing SE and they ought not to be drive-by voters who don't leave comment (-:

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the idea is interesting. It would mean that the Stack would get public exposure outside of search engines. Perhaps, maybe we should be doing more events in the real world. Perhaps expos at high schools and universities would encourage people to learn more on our sites. I myself have never seen such an event, but would support stack if it started to.

Comment: What does going to events in the real world have to do with having on-site competitions?

Comment: I guess he's extrapolating?

Comment: DaMax - Stack Exchange already supports real world events. I have attended events on behalf of SE, and as a speaker wearing SE swag, and giving prizes of SE swag at industry events. This is unrelated to the question though.